# Does a Linksys WMP110 Wireless Card work?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, 64-bit

Does the linksys WMP110 "just work" for Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit?

Answer (score 2):

If [Linksys WMP110 v1](http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/Linksys_WMP110_v1) is the desired [card](http://www.modem-help.co.uk/Linksys/WMP110-RangePlus-Wireless-PCI-Adapter.html). It seems to be that the chipset-manufacturer is 
[Atheros Communications, Inc.](http://www.modem-help.co.uk/Linksys/WMP110-RangePlus-Wireless-PCI-Adapter.html) Their wireless driver [ath9k](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k) is opensource, so the card should work. As I see it uses the chipset [**AR5008** / **AR5416**](http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/Linksys_WMP110_v1). My wireless card is a *TP-Link TL-WN951N*, it uses the same chips and I have a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/1032826) with the ath9k driver.

For [Linksys WMP110 v2](http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/Linksys_WMP110_v2) also exits a [linux driver](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/rt2800pci).